# Changing Country in Google Play

Tags: android

I am publishing an application on Google Play. Presently,this application is having data for two countries. So I want to publish this app for both the countries. But later data will be added to some other countries on to the server which will be fetched by this app. So can I add some more countries, just by checking the countries, in the future without changing anything(viz.; app name, package name, version and etc). Please guide me.. Thanx in advance..

Comment: Yes it may, but you can always change the version number to do incremental changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It can be done. You just need to check for which country/ies your app has got the data. But It might take some time for this updation.

Comment: Thnx. ws worried y ths chnge is not seen yet. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. just by checkin more countries it will work.